# Check for session timeout asp .net

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Check whether Session is Expired or not in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480110/how-to-check-whether-session-is-expired-or-not-in-asp-net)

What is the best way for a page to detect if a session has timed out in the code behind?
I found the below code in a blog (http://mattslay.com/detecting-session-timeout-in-asp-net/). Is is ok or is there a better way?

```
if (Context.Session != null && Context.Session.IsNewSession)
{
     string cookieHeader = Page.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
     if ((null != cookieHeader) && (cookieHeader.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
          return true; // timeout occured
     else
          return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to treat this treatment in your `Global.asax file`

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Here you execute your treatments about end session
}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end.aspx